# The best practice to create different screens layouts

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I'm developing an Android app that is capable of running on different screens, I'm using on of the approachs explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which is:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

I know that the `Layout` folder is the default one that the app goes to when not finding the desired layout in the specified folder, but I want to ask if I've like Two Layouts (`layout_A` & `layout_B`) and `layout_A` is differ from one case to another of the mentioned three cases(**handset**, **7'**, **10'**) so that it will be exist in the three folders, but the `layout_B` is differ from **handset** to **7'** but is the same from **7'** to **10'**, am i suppose to copy/paste it from the `600dp` folder to the `720dp` folder ?(as if the layout folder is the default as always) , or it's enough to put in the `600dp` folder and it will be accessed from there in the case of `720dp`?.

ie. if I've the Layouts folders as the following:

```
layout/layout_A.xml       //A1
      /layout_B.xml       //B1

layout-sw600dp/layout_A.xml      //A2
              /layout_B.xml      //B2

layout-sw720dp/layout_A.xml      //A3
```

And now I'm trying to run `layout_B.xml` on a 10' tablet, what's the layout that my app will pick ?**(B1 || B2)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the [configuration examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples) it would work if you put your `Layout_B` only inside the `res/layout-sw600dp/` folder and it will be used by a `720dp` device as well, because the `sw` means "smallest width" and a 720dp device provides the requested minimum of 600dp (and extends this requirement by additional 120dp), which means in your case the app will pick **B2** for the **10'** tablet.

Testing both configurations will make this sure in a minute.